# recognizing faces using python and pil

Tags: python, dictionary, python-imaging-library, face-recognition

as part of a final year project I wrote a program which receives an image, analyzes it, and compares it to a dictionary of data. Ultimately, the program prints the name of the person who appears in the picture. However, the program seems to make a considerable amount of mistakes in recognition, and thus my request for help and/or ideas.

**How does it work ?**
First, 4 photos of specific men/women (Obama,Trump,Hillary Clinton..) (Each one has 4 photos) were imported. Using Pil, the program then analyzes each and every picture's pixels, and different functions produce different "attributes" for every picture:

1. averagecolor - returns a list of the average color of the photo [Ravg,Gavg,Bavg]
2. differenceUpDown - returns the difference between the average color in the upper side and the average color in the lower side [(Rup-Rdown),(Gup-Gdown),(Bup-Bdown)]
3. differenceRightLeft - same thing as the previous one, just right-left.

At this point, a function called "Massavg" then calculates the avg of those 3 attributes. (In other words, at this point each and every photo is represented by a 3 dimensional constant [x,y,z], which is the average of the 3 attributes).

Then, for each and every person (e.g. Obama) a function calculates the average of the different photos that were imported.

I also created a "Faces dictionary", that look something like this:

```
facesdictionary= {'trump': ([151.60, 107.10, 89.58],31.53) , 'obama': ([121.53, 84.71, 65.4],24.60), 'willsmith': ([118.70, 78.91, 54.58],27.26),'clinton':([137.78, 107.65, 86.53],23.69)}
```

A final function called "Facial Recognition" then receives a photo and immediately calculates the distance to each and every entry in the dictionary. It then print the "Key", whose value is the closest match.

As I said, the recognition is not very good, and makes a lot of mistakes. I would very much like to hear more ideas regarding **further attributes**.

Attached is the code. Thank you very much !

```
from  PIL import Image
import math
import numpy as np
humansdb = open('HumansDB.txt', "ab+")

img =Image.open( './Obama.jpg' )
trump =Image.open( './Trump.jpg' )
clinton = Image.open( './Clinton.jpg' )
boyega = Image.open( './Boyega.jpg' )
obama2 = Image.open( './Obama2.jpg' )
obama3 = Image.open( './Obama3.jpg' )
obama4 = Image.open( './Obama4.jpg' )
obama5 = Image.open( './Obama5.jpg' )
obamaface = Image.open( './ObamaFace.jpg' )
obamacopy = Image.open( './ObamaCopy.jpg' )
obamatest = Image.open( './ObamaTest.jpg' )
obamalaugh = Image.open( './obamatestlaugh.png' )
obamatest2 = Image.open( './ObamaTest2.jpg' )
obamatest3 = Image.open( './ObamaTest3.jpg' )
obamatest4 =  Image.open( './ObamaTest4.jpg' )
willsmith =  Image.open( './WillSmith.jpg' )
willsmith2 =  Image.open( './WillSmith2.jpg' )
willsmith3 =  Image.open( './WillSmith3.jpg' )
willsmith4 =  Image.open( './WillSmith4.jpg' )
trump2 = Image.open( './Trump2.jpg' )
trump3 = Image.open( './Trump3.jpg' )
trump4 = Image.open( './Trump4.jpg' )
trumpstranger = Image.open( './trumpstranger.jpg' )
trumpstranger2 = Image.open( './trumpstranger2.jpg' )
willsmithstranger = Image.open( './Willsmithstranger.jpg' )
clinton2 = Image.open( './Clinton2.jpg' )
clinton3 = Image.open( './Clinton3.jpg' )
clinton4 = Image.open( './Clinton4.jpg' )
clinton5 = Image.open( './Clinton5.jpg' )
clintontest = Image.open( './ClintonTest.jpg' )
someone = Image.open( './someone.jpg' ) #will smith
someone2 = Image.open( './someone2.jpg' )#trump
someone3 = Image.open( './someone3.jpg' )#clinton
ninecolors =  Image.open( './NineColors.jpg' )
someone4 = Image.open( './someone4.jpg' )#clinton
someone5 = Image.open( './someone5.jpg' )#trump
#PuttingPixels
'''
width, height = img.size
def putpixels(r,g,b):
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            img.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
'''



#Average color attribution:
def averagecolor(wstart,wend,hstart,hend,image):
    redcolor = []
    bluecolor = []
    greencolor = []
    for x in range(wstart,wend):
        for y in range(hstart,hend):
            r,g,b = image.getpixel((x,y))
            redcolor.append(r)
            greencolor.append(g)
            bluecolor.append(b)
    red = sum(redcolor)/(len(redcolor))
    green = sum(greencolor)/(len(greencolor))
    blue = sum(bluecolor)/(len(bluecolor))
    colorattribution = [red,green,blue]
    return colorattribution

#obamavgcolor = averagecolor(0,width,0,height,img)

#Differnce Between up and down color attribution:
def differenceupdown(image):
    width, height = image.size
    avgdown = averagecolor(0,width,0,int(0.5*height),image) 
    avgup = averagecolor(0,width,int(0.5*height),height,image)
    differenceupdown = [abs(avgdown[i]-avgup[i]) for i in range(0,3)]
    return differenceupdown

#obamadifference = differenceupdown(img)

#Difference Between right and left color attribution:

def differencerightleft(image):
    width, height = image.size
    avgright = averagecolor(0,int(0.5*width),0,height,image) 
    avgleft = averagecolor(int(0.5*width),width,0,height,image)
    differencerightleft = [abs(avgright[i]-avgleft[i]) for i in range(0,3)]
    return differencerightleft


# NEW 12/06/2016 - 9 More Attributes, Dividing the picture into 9 parts and Calculating the AVG color for each part



def NinePartsAvgColors(image):
    width, height = image.size
    avg1 = averagecolor(0,int((1/3.0)*width),0,int((1/3.0)*height),image) 
    avg2 = averagecolor(int((1/3.0)*width),int((2/3.0)*width),0,int((1/3.0)*height),image) 
    avg3 = averagecolor(int((2/3.0)*width),width,0,int((1/3.0)*height),image) 
    avg4 = averagecolor(0,int((1/3.0)*width),int((1/3.0)*height),int((2/3.0)*height),image) 
    avg5 = averagecolor(int((1/3.0)*width),int((2/3.0)*width),int((1/3.0)*height),int((2/3.0)*height),image) 
    avg6 = averagecolor(int((2/3.0)*width),width,int((1/3.0)*height),int((2/3.0)*height),image) 
    avg7 = averagecolor(0,int((1/3.0)*width),int((2/3.0)*height),height,image) 
    avg8 = averagecolor(int((1/3.0)*width),int((2/3.0)*width),int((2/3.0)*height),height,image) 
    avg9 = averagecolor(int((2/3.0)*width),width,int((2/3.0)*height),height,image) 
    return avg1,avg2,avg3,avg4,avg5,avg6,avg7,avg8,avg9
#print NinePartsAvgColors(obama3)

#Calculating 3 dimensional average:

def massavg(image):
    width, height = image.size
    imgavgcolor = averagecolor(0,width,0,height,image)
    diffupdown = differenceupdown(image)
    diffrightleft = differencerightleft(image)
    nine = NinePartsAvgColors(image)
    massaverage = [float(imgavgcolor[i]+diffupdown[i]+diffrightleft[i]+nine[0][i]+nine[1][i]+nine[2][i]+nine[3][i]+nine[4][i]+nine[5][i]+nine[6][i]+nine[7][i]+nine[8][i])/12 for i in range(0,3)]
    return massaverage
#widthtest, heighttest = trump2.size
#print averagecolor(0,widthtest,0,heighttest,trump2),differenceupdown(trump2),differencerightleft(trump2),NinePartsAvgColors(trump2)

def spacedistance((x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2)):
    xd = x2-x1
    yd = y2-y1
    zd = z2-z1
    distance = math.sqrt(xd**2+yd**2+zd**2)
    return distance
#print spacedistance(massavg(img),massavg(trump))


def avg_photos_mass(list_of_mass_averages):
    stdphotos = np.std(list_of_mass_averages)
    length = len(list_of_mass_averages)
    onedimension = [list_of_mass_averages[i][0] for i in range(0,length)]
    onedimensionavg = sum(onedimension)/float(len(onedimension))
    twodimension = [list_of_mass_averages[i][1] for i in range(0,length)]
    twodimensionavg = sum(twodimension)/float(len(twodimension))
    threedimension = [list_of_mass_averages[i][2] for i in range(0,length)]
    threedimensionavg = sum(threedimension)/float(len(threedimension))
    avg_photos = []
    avg_photos.append(onedimensionavg)
    avg_photos.append(twodimensionavg)
    avg_photos.append(threedimensionavg)
    return avg_photos,stdphotos
#print avg_photos_mass([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,18]])


#print spacedistance(obamavg,massavg(boyega))
#print avg_photos_mass([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])[1]

'''
humansdb.write("\nhellooooo")

humansdb.close()
humansdb = open('HumansDB.txt', "r")
for line in  humansdb.readlines():
    print line
humansdb.close()
'''
def Ultimate_3d_avg(listofphotos):
    averagesofphotos = map(massavg,listofphotos)
    point = avg_photos_mass(averagesofphotos)[0]
    std = avg_photos_mass(averagesofphotos)[1]
    return point,std

#Calculating People's Averages:
'''
trumpavg = Ultimate_3d_avg([trump,trump2,trump3,trump4])[0]
print trumpavg
willsmithavg = Ultimate_3d_avg([willsmith,willsmith2,willsmith3,willsmith4])[0]
print willsmithavg
obamavg = Ultimate_3d_avg([img,obama2,obama3,obama4,obama5])[0]
print obamavg
clintonavg = Ultimate_3d_avg([clinton,clinton2,clinton3,clinton4,clinton5])[0]
print clintonavg
'''
#Calculating People's STD:
'''
willsmithstd = Ultimate_3d_avg([willsmith,willsmith2,willsmith3,willsmith4])[1]
print willsmithstd
obamastd = Ultimate_3d_avg([img,obama2,obama3,obama4,obama5])[1]
print obamastd
trumpstd = Ultimate_3d_avg([trump,trump2,trump3,trump4])[1]
print trumpstd
clintonstd = Ultimate_3d_avg([clinton,clinton2,clinton3,clinton4,clinton5])[1]
print clintonstd
'''


facesdictionary= {'trump': ([151.60, 107.10, 89.58],31.53) , 'obama': ([121.53, 84.71, 65.4],24.60), 'willsmith': ([118.70, 78.91, 54.58],27.26),'clinton':([137.78, 107.65, 86.53],23.69)}



#print facesdictionary.items()


def facial_recognition(imageofsomething):
    imageavg =  massavg(imageofsomething)
    database = facesdictionary.items()
    minkey = database[0][0]
    bestmatch = (spacedistance(imageavg,database[0][1][0]))/(database[0][1][1]) # Distance/STD
    for i in range(0,len(database)):
        distance = (spacedistance(imageavg,database[i][1][0]))/(database[i][1][1])
        if(distance<bestmatch):
            bestmatch = distance
            minkey = database[i][0]
    return minkey,bestmatch

print facial_recognition(someone5)
#print massavg(trump),massavg(trump2),massavg(trump3),massavg(trump4)
```